# Safely casting <? extends Response> to <Response>

Tags: java, types, casting, extends

I have an HTTP executor class:

`Future<? extends Response> future = service.apply(request).toJavaFuture();`

Now I want to remove the `? extends` part of this, because I don't want to make it so generic for the caller. Basically, I want to return `Future<Response>`.

*From my point of view:*

`x extends y`

Would mean `x` is `y`, and `y` is not `x`.

That would mean `x` can be casted to `y`.

In my eyes, this can be done safely, because `x` always extends `y`.

**Why is the following unsafe?**

```
    Future<? extends Response> future = service.apply(request).toJavaFuture();

    Future<Response> futureResponse = (Future<Response>) future;
```

Comment: "because I don't want to make it so generic for the caller" This doesn't make sense to me. They can already do this safely `Response response = future.get()`. What's the problem...?

Comment: @Michael This started because I got a complaint in SonarQube about it and started thinking about why I would return `? extends ...` in the first place, not really an issue but more curiosity

Comment: @Randy What's the sonarqube message?

Comment: @Michael reference: https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/RSPEC-1452

Comment: [Generics and Subtyping](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/subtype.html)

Comment: Wow Oleksandr, thank you! This answers my question perfectly.

Comment: @Randy You mean that's the issue you're trying to address by casting and returning `Future<Response>`... Right?

Comment: @ernest_k Yes, the sonarqube link you mean I hope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `Future<? extends Response>` variable can be assigned a `Future<Response>` or a `Future<ResponseSubClass1>` or a `Future<ResponseSubClass2>`.

A `Future<ResponseSubClass1>` instance cannot be safely assigned to a `Future<Response>` variable, since that would allow assigning a `ResponseSubClass2` to a `Future<ResponseSubClass1>`.

Therefore, your attempted casting is unsafe.

Comment: This probably explains the reason for the warning, but not really why casting to `Future<Response>` is deemed unsafe here, conceptually at least. The code isn't casting to a `Future<ResponseSubclass*>` after all...

Comment: I realise that I cannot pass it down as generic as it is, but I do think that I should be able to cast `ResponseSubClass2` to `Response` if that is its direct parent class right? Because (in my eyes) that cannot go wrong as it is of type `Response` already?

Comment: @ernest_k it is casting an instance that could potentially be a `Future<ResponseSubclass*>` (since such an instance might be referenced by the `future` variable) to a `Future<Response>` type.

Comment: @Randy ResponseSubClass2  being a sub-class of Response does not make `Future<ResponseSubClass2 >` a sub-class of `Future<Response>`.

Comment: @Eran I agree. But that should be safe. Problem would be potentially casting one subclass of `Response` to another, which isn't the case here.

Answer (score 2):

I would say that this is a limitation of the compiler with regards to generic type parameters. The compiler knows that you are parameterising the class but it does not have any context for how it is used.

Your `Future` is a data holder. You cannot put anything into it, you can only get requests out of it. In this case, your expectation that `Future<? extends Response>` and `Future<Response>` will behave the same way, thus be safe to cast, is perfectly reasonable. Both of these things are suppliers of requests. The exact instances might be subclasses, but whatever we get out of our `Future` will definitely implement the methods of `Request`, so this cast seems like it should be safe.

The problem comes when you have classes that are not pure suppliers, but when they are consuming data. Suppose we added a method to `Future` to set the value:

```
interface Future<T>
{
    void setValue(T value);
    //...
}
```

And we have a `Future<? extends Response>` which was created as a `Future<ChildResponse>`. When we cast it `Future<Response>`, we can now call `setValue` with a `Response`, whereas before casting we would have needed a `ChildResponse`. This is the reason why the cast is not deemed safe.

Effectively the compiler just isn't clever enough to differentiate between the two cases and so the best decision is to always declare the cast as unsafe. Even if the compiler could draw the distinction, the issue is further complicated by the fact that an interface could change - suppose `Future` were changed as described above - so that a cast that was previously safe would no longer be.

In this case, I would personally feel fine about suppressing the warning. Casting is all about making assertions to the compiler that you have information that it doesn't, which is the situation you have there.